# js and regex exclude {} from string

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to exclude the {} from a string such as below with regex, but so far the {} is still in the created array. Please see jsfiddle example (example part of larger code so I understand the code can be simplified). Resultat is:

```
["{1", "\"FAAS\"}"]
```

But would like

```
["1", "\"FAAS\""]
```

https://jsfiddle.net/173os8w6/

```
var objectX = {};
  var text = `{1 "FAAS"}`;
  var lines = text.split('\n');
  for (var line = 0; line < lines.length; line++) {
        const regex = /{([^\s"]+)|"([^"]*)"}/g;  
        var row2 = [];                 
        let result = "";
        while(result = regex.exec(lines[line])) {
          row2.push(result[0]); //push parts to array
        } 
        console.log(row2);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to analyze the captures and add the right values accordingly:

```js
while(result = regex.exec(lines[line])) {
    if (result[1]) {
        row2.push(result[1]);
    } else {
        row2.push(result[2]);
    }
}
```

Here is your fixed JavaScript demo:

```js
var objectX = {};
var text = `{1 "FAAS"}`;
var lines = text.split('\n');
for (var line = 0; line < lines.length; line++) {
  const regex = /{([^\s"]+)|"([^"]*)"}/g;
  var row2 = [];
  let result = "";
  while (result = regex.exec(lines[line])) {
    if (result[1]) {
      row2.push(result[1]);
    } else {
      row2.push(result[2]);
    }
  }
  console.log(row2);
}
```